# How to make rounded borders in HTML for IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, css

I wanted to have a round table corner inside the Asp.net HTML pages ,so I wrote the following HTML code to be visible in Chrome & Mozila and also IE (I am using IE9).

```
<style type="text/css">.round{-webkit-border-radius:15px;-moz-border-radius:15px;border-radius:15px}
</style>
```

Every thing is right except in IE9 .What's the problem .

Comment: Googling `rounded borders ie9` gives me [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589503(v=vs.85).aspx) which contains a warning about using the right doctype.

Comment: To my knowledge, your code should work, however, try to put the IE statement first (so the last statement in your css first.) I am not sure how IE reads it, but I always put that first, and I never have problems with it. And close your CSS statement, you left it open by not putting ; behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine. IE9 uses the unpredixed border-radius.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius

Add this to your `<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

This should make sure IE9 runs border-radius.

Comment: I checked Reinder linked and i realized that when i run the browser it comes up with IE7, so i have to press F12 and then change it to IE9 Standard . now do you in IE option how can i make IE9 as default view?

Comment: IE should be your default view unless someone has told it to run in IE7 mode. Look for this metatag <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" > and remove it.

Comment: Ok , but where can i find <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" > ? is it inside my current page.aspx?

Comment: It will be in your <head> if it exists.

Comment: Then something's gone very very wrong. Do you have a live link?